# dplyr mutate with a monotonically increasing value within each group based bundling rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame such as this one where ID is the main grouping variable and the type represents a transaction type. Type 'a' is the precursor to type 'b' transaction. I want to be able to assign unique transaction Ids to all ([a]+[b]{1}) patters within the 'group' formed for each ID.

```
> df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), type =     c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'))
> df
   id type
1   1    a
2   1    a
3   1    b
4   1    a
5   1    b
6   2    a
7   2    b
8   3    a
9   3    b
10  3    a
11  3    b
12  4    a
13  4    a
14  4    a
15  4    b
```

The resulting data frame should look like this, although the tid values are arbitrary here, and just need to be some unique ID within each 'transaction group' within the overall group.

```
> dfnew <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), type = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), tid = c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 100, 100, 100, 200))
> dfnew
   id type tid
1   1    a 100
2   1    a 100
3   1    b 100
4   1    a 200
5   1    b 200
6   2    a 100
7   2    b 100
8   3    a 100
9   3    b 100
10  3    a 200
11  3    b 200
12  4    a 100
13  4    a 100
14  4    a 100
15  4    b 100
>
```

I wrote part of the code that gets me 'mostly' in the proper direction, but I don't know how to mutate with a monotonically increasing value instead of binary values I am currently assigning.

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(tid = ifelse(is.na(lag(type)) | lag(type) == 'a' | (type == 'b' & lag(type) == 'a'), 1, 0))
```

Being able to mutate using a variable that increments is what I need.

Comment: Maybe wrap your binary values in `cumsum()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(tid= sprintf("%03d", head(cumsum(c(F, type=="b")), -1)))
```